# Can I control the "var" of a driver manually?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, drivers

I want to use a driver to open and close a hatch by rotating it on its y axis. So when I move the empty on the z axis the hatch should rotate on the y axis. I locked the empty on a min and max z value because there is something else driven by it. When i move the empty through the full range the other animation is complete but the hatch didn't rotate far enough. I know i can make it rotate further by writing var*2 or more in the driver editor but i don't want to adjust the multiplication of the var until the rotation is correct because it takes too long for multiple hatches. Is there another way to basically set the rotation that is reached when the driver is fully "extended"?[image: the driver/empty controls the landing gear and the hatches, the empty can only be moved .465m on the z axis until the landing gear is inside the box]

Comment: tbh this is not a blender question - but a math question. You have 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and you want to calculate the y = mx + n function for that. (rot_max-rot_min)/(zmax-zmin)*(z-zmin)+rot_min in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice, I see you are working on a Millennium Falcon model ;) If you don't want to go for the maths behind this, instead of using drivers you could use a *Transform* constraint on the hatch with the empty as *Target*.

You can choose which transformations you want to map from one object to the other - in your case *Location* to *Rotation*, and you can use different *Min/Max* values. Also you can decide whether the global or local coordinates are relevant on both objects. This will be necessary since I suspect the empty and the hatches will be parented to a spaceship that can move, so the global positions will be variable.

In the following example I have an empty that can only move from +1 on the Z axis to +3. I created three sets of hatches with three different behaviours:

1. rotates 0° to 120° from Z +1 to +2
2. rotates 0° to 120° from Z +1 to +3
3. rotates 0° to 90° from Z +2 to +3

[image: different hatches]

As you can see, 1. and 2. both rotate 120°, but the first hatch is opened quicker than the second. The 3. starts to open later and rotates just 90° (by the way, that's for the left hatch doors, the right doors have the corresponding negative angles). **//EDIT:** No negative angles, see last paragraph.

These are the settings of the left doors. The *Target* is the empty, both *Target* and *Owner* are set to *Local Space* so that when you parent everything to another object, they can move around with it and still work correctly.

Under *Map From* I chose *Location* and the Z *Min* and *Max* values for the range in which I want the hatch to open. The *Map To* is set to *Rotation*, important now is to set the *Y Source Axis* (because I want to rotate them on Y) to Z, because I want the Z value of the empty to drive the rotation. As *Min* and *Max* I set the range for the opening angles.

[image: constraint settings]

This is an example to show that it works even when parented to another object:

[image: parented constraints]

Of course there are much more settings for the *Transform* constraint. And just after finishing all this I realized you don't have to put *Transform* constraints on all doors. In my file I just have them on the left doors, the right doors have *Copy Rotation* constraints with inverted Y axis. This way you only have to adjust the angles for one of the doors per hatch.

[image: copy rotation constraint]

[image]